# Secondary Custom UserStore using JDBCUserStoreManagerin WSO IS 5.9

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Need to create a secondary custom UserStore using JDBCUserStoreManager, I have a usertable with username and password as columns.

I need to configure the datasource, and then customer Userstore Manager class and using the username and password from the usertable I should be able to login to WSO2 IS 5.9

Thanks,
Subhash

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this [doc](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager/) to write a custom userstore manager

1. You have to extend [JDBCUserStoreManager](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.5.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/JDBCUserStoreManager.java) class and overide the
   methods.
2. Then can build the source code and deploy the artifact
   into dropins folder as mentioned in the[doc](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager/).

When you are configuring the secondary userstore manager, you can point to the custom userstore manager. Please folow these two docs ([doc1](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-user-stores/#secondary-user-stores-optional), [doc2](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-secondary-user-stores/)) to configure secondary userstores

Comment: I followed the doc as mentioned above i,e extending the JDBCUserStoreManager, https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/writing-a-custom-user-store-manager/ but i got the error as  [2020-02-01 00:15:25,610] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} - Cannot start User Manager Core bundle org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Required property 'TenantManager' not found for the primary UserStoreManager in user_mgt.xml. Cannot start server!
        at o